# How to copy .xlsx complete workbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have the solution to copy .xls workbook in java but not able to copy .xlsx workbook.
Anybody have solution.
I have searched google, stackoverflow and found solution only to copy xls files.

Comment: Add the sample code you have tried, then only will be able to help you find solution. Specify exact issue you are facing.

Comment: @MandarPandit OP wants a software library that supports the Microsoft Office Excel 2007+ file format.

Comment: Probably, Apache POI is a library that the author wants.

Comment: If this is just about copying the xlsx files this can be done using [Files.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29), if java version is JDK 7 and above.
Otherwise Apache POI is the library which can be used for the copying purpose.
But I found this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31941691/1814867) regarding the same issue using Apache POI. You might want to refer this.

Comment: @MandarPandit no i need to copy and add a extra column to new file and allow it to download by clicking link..

Comment: @SergeyChepurnov i am already using Apache POI library to creat new xls/xlsx file. but i'm not able to copy xlsx file only using apache poi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't test my code. Just wrote it to give you a basic idea of what to do.

```
public class CopyXSSFWorkbook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Read xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook oldWorkbook = null;
        try {
            oldWorkbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(new File("old.xlsx"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        final XSSFWorkbook newWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

        // Copy style source
        final StylesTable oldStylesSource = oldWorkbook.getStylesSource();
        final StylesTable newStylesSource = newWorkbook.getStylesSource();

        oldStylesSource.getFonts().forEach(font -> newStylesSource.putFont(font, true));
        oldStylesSource.getFills().forEach(fill -> newStylesSource.putFill(new XSSFCellFill(fill.getCTFill())));
        oldStylesSource.getBorders()
                .forEach(border -> newStylesSource.putBorder(new XSSFCellBorder(border.getCTBorder())));

        // Copy sheets
        for (int sheetNumber = 0; sheetNumber < oldWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetNumber++) {
            final XSSFSheet oldSheet = oldWorkbook.getSheetAt(sheetNumber);
            final XSSFSheet newSheet = newWorkbook.createSheet(oldSheet.getSheetName());

            newSheet.setDefaultRowHeight(oldSheet.getDefaultRowHeight());
            newSheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(oldSheet.getDefaultColumnWidth());

            // Copy content
            for (int rowNumber = oldSheet.getFirstRowNum(); rowNumber < oldSheet.getLastRowNum(); rowNumber++) {
                final XSSFRow oldRow = oldSheet.getRow(rowNumber);
                if (oldRow != null) {
                    final XSSFRow newRow = newSheet.createRow(rowNumber);
                    newRow.setHeight(oldRow.getHeight());

                    for (int columnNumber = oldRow.getFirstCellNum(); columnNumber < oldRow
                            .getLastCellNum(); columnNumber++) {
                        newSheet.setColumnWidth(columnNumber, oldSheet.getColumnWidth(columnNumber));

                        final XSSFCell oldCell = oldRow.getCell(columnNumber);
                        if (oldCell != null) {
                            final XSSFCell newCell = newRow.createCell(columnNumber);

                            // Copy value
                            setCellValue(newCell, getCellValue(oldCell));

                            // Copy style
                            XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = newWorkbook.createCellStyle();
                            newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
                            newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            oldWorkbook.close();
            newWorkbook.write(new FileOutputStream("new.xlsx"));
            newWorkbook.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

    private static void setCellValue(final XSSFCell cell, final Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            cell.setCellValue((boolean) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Byte) {
            cell.setCellValue((byte) value);
        } else if (value instanceof Double) {
            cell.setCellValue((double) value);
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            if (value.startsWith("=")) { 
                //  Formula String  
                cell.setCellFormula(value.substring(1));
            } else {
                cell.setCellValue(cstr);
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    private static Object getCellValue(final XSSFCell cell) {
        switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
            case BOOLEAN:
                return cell.getBooleanCellValue(); // boolean
            case ERROR:
                return cell.getErrorCellValue(); // byte
            case NUMERIC:
                return cell.getNumericCellValue(); // double
            case STRING:
            case BLANK:
                return cell.getStringCellValue(); // String
            case FORMULA:
                return  "=" + cell.getCellFormula(); // String for formula
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If anyone wants a simpler procedure just use Files.copy:

```
File originalWb = new File("orginalWb.xlsx"); 
File clonedWb = new File("clonedWb.xlsx");
Files.copy(originalWb.toPath(), clonedW.toPath());
```

No need for any bloated code

Answer (score 1):

Using Apache POI XSSF library:

```
public void copyFile(String sourcePath, String destinationPath) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(sourcePath));
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(destinationPath);
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    workbook.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Clone a workbook in memory (if you can efford it):

```
public static Workbook cloneWorkbook(final Workbook workbook) {
  try {
    final ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(4096);
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    return WorkbookFactory.create(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()));
  } catch (final IOException ex) {
    log.warn("Error cloning workbook", ex);
    return null; // or throw exception
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apache POI [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

POI performs these steps on `XLS/XLSX` File. `XLS: HSSFWorkbook, XLSX: XSSFWorkbook`

1. Read the File as Stream (FileStream): SystemFile to JavaFileObject
2. Create a WorkBook form Stream. Stream to XSSFWorkbook-JavaObject
3. Using POI functions you can perform CURD operations on Java Workbook Object.
4. Convert Java Workbook Object to file/stream.

NOTE: Index Starts form 0 for Row/Column/Sheet.

Following operations are performed on Sheets:

> XLSX File with `Sheet1, Sheet2`
> getSheet_RemoveOthers(Sheet1). XLSX File:`Sheet1`

```java
public static XSSFSheet getSheet_RemoveOthers(String sourceFileSheetName) {
    XSSFSheet srcSheet = workBook.getSheet(sourceFileSheetName);
    //Sheet srcSheet = oldWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
    
    int srcSheetIndex = workBook.getSheetIndex(srcSheet);
    System.out.println("srcSheetIndex:"+srcSheetIndex);
    
    int numberOfSheets = workBook.getNumberOfSheets();
    for (int indexAt = 0; indexAt < numberOfSheets; indexAt++) {
        if (srcSheetIndex == indexAt) {
            System.out.println("sourceFileSheetName:"+indexAt);
        } else {
            String sheetName = workBook.getSheetName(indexAt);
            System.out.println("Removing sheetName:"+sheetName);
            workBook.removeSheetAt(indexAt);
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("getSheetName : "+ srcSheet.getSheetName() );
    int totalRows = srcSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    System.out.println("Total Number of Rows : "+ totalRows );
    
    return srcSheet;
}
```

> XSSFSheet.cloneSheet(Sheet1). XLSX File:`Sheet1, Sheet1 (2)`

```java
public static XSSFSheet cloneSheet(String sourceFileSheetName) {
    Sheet srcSheet = workBook.getSheet(sourceFileSheetName);
    int srcSheetIndex = workBook.getSheetIndex(srcSheet);
    System.out.println("srcSheetIndex:"+srcSheetIndex);
    XSSFSheet cloneSheet = workBook.cloneSheet(srcSheetIndex);
    return cloneSheet;
}
```

---

Full-Length Example:

```java
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
public class POI_XLSX_Report {
    static String filePath = "C:/Yash/",
            sourceFile = filePath+"POIExcel.xlsx", sourceFileSheetName = "Sheet1",
            destinationFile = filePath+"POIExcelCopy.xlsx";
    
    static XSSFWorkbook workBook;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File mySrcFile = new File(sourceFile);
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(mySrcFile);
        
        workBook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create( stream );
        
        XSSFSheet sheet_RemoveOthers = getSheet_RemoveOthers(sourceFileSheetName);
        setSheetValue(sheet_RemoveOthers, 4, 6, "Val2");
        
        // New Sheet with exact copy of Source-Sheet
        XSSFSheet cloneSheet = cloneSheet(sourceFileSheetName);
        setSheetValue(cloneSheet, 4, 6, "Val2");
        
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workBook.write( byteArrayOutputStream );
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        
        File clonedWb = new File(destinationFile);
        //Files.copy(mySrcFile.toPath(), clonedWb.toPath()); If a file is already available then throws exception
        
        // Write the output to a file
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream( clonedWb );
        byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
    }
    public static XSSFSheet getSheet_RemoveOthers(String sourceFileSheetName) {
        // ...
    }
    public static XSSFSheet cloneSheet(String sourceFileSheetName) {
        // ...
    }
    
    public static void setSheetValue(Sheet sheet, int colIndex, int rowIndex, String value) {
        // Row and Column index starts form 0
        rowIndex = rowIndex - 1;
        colIndex = colIndex - 1;
        Row row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        if (row == null) {
            System.out.println("createRow:");
            Row createRow = sheet.createRow(rowIndex);
            row= createRow;
        }
        
        short lastCellNum = row.getLastCellNum();
        System.out.println("Col:"+lastCellNum);
        
        Cell createCell = row.createCell(colIndex, CellType.STRING);
        System.out.println("New cell:"+createCell.getStringCellValue());
        createCell.setCellValue(value);
    }
}
```