# A save confirmation dialog is displayed in the xlsx book that executed cloneSheet with apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Excel : Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (version 2208 build 16.0.15601.20660) 32 bit

apache poi/poi-ooxml : 5.2.3

JDK : openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)

1. Create an Excel workbook.
2. Open that workbook with poi and run colenSheet and save it.
3. When you open a workbook saved with poi in Excel and close it without doing anything, a save confirmation dialog will be displayed.

Code from 2 above.

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    // arrange
    InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("work_test_src.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook xssFBook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);

    // action
    XSSFSheet xssSheet = xssFBook.cloneSheet(0);
    xssSheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).setCellValue("TEST2");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("target/work_test_dst_from_poi.xlsx");
    xssFBook.write(fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    xssFBook.close();

    // assert
    // noop
}
```

Excel screen of 3 above.
[image]

Book saved with poi: work_test_dst_from_poi.xlsx

Book saved in the above save confirmation dialog: work_test_dst_from_excel.xlsx

If you unzip and compare these two, there is a difference.

[image]

From this, the internal structure of xlsx has versions, and the workbook saved with the latest version structure (excel) was saved with the old version structure (poi), which seems to have caused the problem.

When the workbook with the problem was opened again in Excel, it was automatically corrected, so it seems that the save confirmation dialog was displayed when closing without doing anything.

If possible, I would like to prevent the save confirmation dialog from being displayed even if I operate with poi.Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What happens if you `flush()` and `close()` `fos`?

Comment: Unfortunately flush() and close() did not solve the problem. To avoid misidentification, I've also changed the post to verified code.

Comment: I wonder if it would help to `flush()` and `close()` the `fos` _after_ closing the workbook.

Comment: I also tried flush() and close() of fos after closing the workbook, but it had no effect.
To begin with, fos is close()ed when it is processed as ZipPackage in the write method, so the position of flush() and close() seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: What happens to the `XSSFSheet` returned by `cloneSheet()`?

Comment: I understand that when cloneSheet() is called, the cloned sheet will be added to the workbook and a reference to the added instance will be returned, so I don't think I need to do anything with it.

Comment: Wouldn't adding the cloned sheet imply that `xssFBook` is modified prior to writing? You might also look at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64785053/230513), _inter alia_.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
The posted example was created for the purpose of simplifying and understanding the phenomenon. However, I also understood that it is a bad example as an example, so I will change the example code. But running with this code does not solve the problem.
I saw the example, but in this example there is a logic that deletes unnecessary sheets in advance with removeSheetAt(). Unfortunately, if you delete the existing sheet and clone it, this event will not occur until the number of existing sheets existed. Occurs when simply added by cloning.

Comment: I was hoping that `cloneSheet()` could simplify copying.

Comment: The example you showed me does the same thing as the example on this page, except that it calls removeSheetAt() in advance.
Thank you for confirming and replying.

Comment: As you have explored this in a different context, it may be useful to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Comment: OK. I'm posting my own answer as a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not an essential solution, you can avoid the problem by invoking `cloneSheet()` and then `removeSheet()` on the original sheet. However, it is only a one-to-one workaround.

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    // arrange
    InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("work_test_src.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook xssFBook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
    XSSFSheet xssSheet = xssFBook.cloneSheet(0);
    xssSheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).setCellValue("TEST2");
    xssFBook.removeSheetAt(0);

    // action
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("target/work_test_dst_from_poi.xlsx");
    xssFBook.write(fos);
    xssFBook.close();
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();

    // assert
    // noop
}
```

A similar approach is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64785053/230513).